# Recurring Events displaying for multiple weeks in google calendar using ics file

Tags: node.js, angular, calendar, icalendar, recurring-events

I have this `ics file` content

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Calcutta
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:UTC
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20231222T210000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20231228T220000
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,SA
ORGANIZER;CN=xxxxxx.com:mailto:xxxxx.com
UID:dfdfered9
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=xxxx@gmail.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:xxxx@gmail.com
DTSTAMP:20231222T104600
CREATED:20231222T104600
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION(GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:TESTRECICS
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

[image]

In google calendar it is spanning for different weeks also but i want it till 22nd Dec 2023 only.